# Python - Memory leak in single loop when using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-requests, celery

I have a large number of websites that have been mirrored and are on S3.  These websites need to be indexed for search (Google is not an option here), so I have some Celery workers that, when given a list of URLs `aws_keys` do the following:

```
for k in aws_keys:
    try:
        req = requests.get(k, stream = True)
        if req.status_code >= 400:
            raise requests.RequestException('URL [{}] returned status [{}]'.format(k, req.status_code))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.raw.data, 'lxml')
        title = soup.title.text.strip()

        # Extract out the style, script, document and other tags from the soup
        extracts = [s.extract() for s in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]

        # Get the text of the page
        text = soup.getText(' ', strip = True)

        # save to db

        soup.decompose
        req.close()
        req = None
    except (requests.RequestException, AttributeError) as e:
        self.log.error('Exception occurred accessing key [{0}]. Message: [{1}]'.format(cl_id, e.message))
        continue
    except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
        self.log.error('Unicode Exception [{0}]'.format(e.message))
        continue
```

Now, when `aws_keys` is longer than 10000 items or so, I notice the worker process requiring more and more memory to the point that all memory is consumed and a reboot is required.

Now, I suspect there are two places where this can occur: `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. However, since both objects are destroyed in the loop, they should be garbage collected and the memory released.

Comment: just an assumption... does your script behave exactly the same if to set `stream = False`?

Comment: I had looked into that, and it's documented here at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Relevant section:

`If you set stream to True when making a request, Requests cannot release the connection back to the pool unless you consume all the data or call Response.close.`

I'm explicitly calling that close method, after decomposing the BeautifuSoup object

Comment: Dumb Question, but do you have DEBUG = True in the settings file you are using.  That will cause memory leaks for sure.

Comment: @GeorgZimmer `DEBUG` is set to `False`.  I'm currently looking at BeautifulSoup for this, and implementing a direct garbage collect call.

Comment: @Andersson, one side effect of `stream = False` is that BeautifulSoup can't process the request data.  Specifically, 
`Starting new HTTP connection (1): s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Exception occurred accessing key [36161]. Message: ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'text']`